# QuerySet subscripting won't work as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

when got a QuerySet by using filter and it's easy to use the following code to do the change and save operation:

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(owner_id=123)
# suppose qs has 1 or many elements
last_login_time = qs[0].last_login_time
qs[0].last_login_time = datetime.now()    # I expect it can assign the new value, but it won't
assertEquals(qs[0].last_login_time, last_login_time)   # YES, it doesn't change
qs[0].save()   #So it won't update the old record
```

And after figuring this out, the following code will be used instead and it works:

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.filter(owner_id=123)
# suppose qs has 1 or many elements
obj = qs[0]
last_login_time = obj.last_login_time
obj.last_login_time = datetime.now()    # I expect it can assign the new value, but it will
assertNotEquals(obj.last_login_time, last_login_time)   # YES, it does change
obj.save()   #So it will update the old record as expected
```

And I have met some of my friends/colleagues use the first approach to do the record updating. And IMO, it's natural and prone to use. (when you *type qs[0]* and *type obj* , they have the same type)

After reading the code(db.models.query), it can be figured out why.(when you subscript the QuerySet it will use the qs = self._clone() and assigning a value won't change at all)

Possible solutions:

1. make the assigning work for the
   subscripting QuerySet
2. announce the
   above first approach is wrong and
   let the users know it

So I want to ask:

1. Is my question a real issue for django?(I'm wondering why django developer not make it work as expected)
2. What's your suggestion about this issue? And what's your preferred way for such an issue?

Comment: `last_login_time = qs[0].last_login_time` should probably be `old_login_time`

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`update`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) for updating fields in a queryset.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in **update**. But As I mentioned, it's *natural* and *prone* to do it in the first approach but it doesn't work as expected. That's my point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Are you saying this is a bug? I don't think so, it's clearly defined behaviour: the queryset is lazy, but is evaluated when you iterate or slice it. Each time you do slice it, you get a new object. This is the logical consequence of the fact that slicing by itself doesn't cause the non-sliced queryset to be evaluated - if the result isn't already cached, slicing will perform a single database call with a `LIMIT 1` to only get one result. Otherwise, you're left with extremely undesirable side-effects.

Now, if you think this could be better explained in the docs, you're welcome - and encouraged - to submit a bug with a patch that explains it better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with your point mostly. But IMO, I think when I want to get the sliced element and assign it with a new value and save it(i.e update it). It's very *natural* and prone to do it in the first approach(see the question). And I don't find any document to ask the users not do that. As you mentioned, it may need a better document.